# Ubuntu Freeze after Writing Large Amounts of Files in C

Tags: c, ubuntu, freeze

My whole system (Ubuntu 18.04) always freezes after around one hour when my c program continuously writes some logs to files. Each file created is around 100 to 200MB and the total amount of these files before system down is around 40-60GB. Usually, I have 150GB more SSD spaces available at this moment.

I checked system condition by System Monitor but couldn't find any problem. When my program runs, only one of the eight cores has 100% usage. Others are pretty low. Before system down, only 2.5GB of 15.5GB memory are used. Every time I reboot my machine, the latest 4-6 created files are empty. Even though most of them was showing some sizes at the moment of freezing. (looks like they were not actual written to SSD)

My c code can be simplified as below:

```
#define MEM_LEN 50000 
#define FILE_LEN 10000*300

struct log_format {
        long cnt;
        long tv_sec;
        long tv_nsec;
        unsigned int user;
        char rw;
        char pathbuffer[256];
        size_t count;
        long long pos;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    int fd=0;
    struct log_format *addr  = NULL;
    int i=0;
    FILE *file;
    char filestr[20];
    int data_cnt = 0;
    int file_cnt =0;

    // open shared memory device //
    fd = open("/dev/remap_pfn", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("....open shared memory device1 failed\n");
        exit(-1);   }
    // memory mapping to shared memory device //
    addr = mmap(NULL, BUF_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_LOCKED, fd, OFFSET);
    if (!addr) {
        perror("....mmap1 failed\n");
        exit(-1);   }

    // open a file //
    sprintf(filestr, "%d.csv", file_cnt);
    file = fopen(filestr, "w");
    printf("%s created\n",filestr);

    // continuously check the memory replacement of last, and write to file // 
    while(1){

        fprintf(file, "%lu,%lu,%lu,%u,%c,%s,%zu,%lld\n", addr[i].cnt, addr[i].tv_sec,
                                addr[i].tv_nsec, addr[i].user, addr[i].rw, addr[i].pathbuffer,
                                addr[i].count, addr[i].pos);
        i++;
        data_cnt++;
        if(i>=MEM_LEN)
            i=0;

        // when reaching a threshold, create another file to write //
        if(data_cnt>=FILE_LEN){
            data_cnt = 0;
            fclose(file);
            file_cnt++;

            // open a file //
            sprintf(filestr, "%d.csv", file_cnt);
            file = fopen(filestr, "w");
            printf("%s created\n",filestr);
        }
    }

    fclose(file);   

    return 0;
}
```

I didn't find any error message from syslog & kern.log. It just freezes.
Does anyone have ideas what could be the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Can it be that your computer is overheated after 1 hour?

Comment: Post definition of `struct log_format, MEM_LEN`, a [mcve]

Comment: Tip: check the return value from all I/O functions `fopen(), fprintf(), ...` to see if the  problem is reported there.

Comment: I added struct log_format, MEM_LEN to my code. It's hard to post a reproducible example here since my application is reading a RAMDisk where has the logs from our customized kernel. log_format follows the format in the RAMDisk.

Comment: Aha.  So the problem could have to do with that customized kernel, or the ramdisk where the data is coming from, and nothing to do with the logfile-writing the posted code is doing!  (To rule this possibility out you could try temporarily commenting out the `fprintf` line in your code, and rerunning.  If it still hangs after an hour, your logging code probably isn't the problem.)

Comment: I saw some messages in syslog about CPU: `CPUn: Package temperature above threshold, cpu clock throttled` and `CPUn: Package temperature/speed normal`. However, it was 10min before the freeze happened.

Comment: That is interesting Question, How you check the system condition, send commands outputs. Check user number of open files `/proc/sys/fs/file-max`

Comment: I think you reach to maximum files limit, use [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux) to change limit

Comment: I did close each file before I open/create a new one. I run my program again and tested commands in the link, currently 37383 file opened over 1611117 file-max.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add some delays into my While loop, to slow down the Write:
(since 1 nano second is still too long for the loop, I make it only Sleep per 10 runs)

```
While(1){
struct timespec ts = {0,1L};
        if(data_cnt%10==0)
            nanosleep(&ts, NULL);
......
}
```

The freeze problem seems gone now.

So... what might be the reason for this? For now, I only saw Write becoming slower and CPU loading decreased to 50% for that core. Is there a write buffer in between and my program exceeded its limit and crushed the system?

(I will also keep track if it is a overheated problem resulting in machine down)